# Splitting an sf object by a character without removing it's geometry in R

Tags: r, split, r-sf

I am trying to `split` an `sf` object by a column that is specified by a character vector. Typically with `data.frame` objects I would use the `[]` to specify the column to use the `split` function on. For example, if I wanted to split North Carolina by county names:

```r
library(sf)

# Set field to split on
splitField <- "NAME"

# Read-in data
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))

# Split by splitField
ncSplit <- split(nc, f = nc[, splitField])
```

However this produces:

```r
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

I have a feeling this is due to the difference between `class(nc[, splitField])` and `class(nc$NAME)`, as using `$` works when splitting. But using `$` will not allow me to split `nc` by a specified `splitField` and I would have to hard code it in.

Another thing I could do would be to remove it's geometry (i.e. `st_geometry(nc) <- NULL`) and turn it into a `data.frame`, which I do not want to do.

I need some help. How can I split a `sf` object by a specified character vector in `R`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is becaue `nc[, splitField]` isn't returning a single vector, it is returning a two column `sf` data frame with `NAME` and `geometry`.

If you you adjust the call to:

```
ncSplit <- split(nc, f = nc[[splitField]])
```

The indexing will return just the factor and then `split()` will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I did not know use the double brackets in that way.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the response by Nate posted in 2019 did not work for me anymore in 2022. Instead it returned the error message:

```r
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i) : undefined columns selected
```

Fortunately, `dplyr::group_split()` with the `!!` (bang-bang) operator from `rlang` was able to handle the split as desired. In the example in the question it would be:

```r
library(dplyr)
ncSplit <- nc |>
    group_split(!!as.name(splitField))
```